# Add a texture on a sphere by Urhosharp

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, urhosharp

I'm using Xamarin.Forms + Urhosharp, I've got a problem to set texture from an image on a sphere. The problem is that texture.Load or texture.SetData always returns false. I did try different methods like SetData, Load, resize texture and image (to a power of 2 number) and ... but none of them worked. Here is my code:

```
    private async void CreateScene()
    {
        Input.SubscribeToTouchEnd(OnTouched);

        _scene = new Scene();
        _octree = _scene.CreateComponent<Octree>();

        _plotNode = _scene.CreateChild();
        var baseNode = _plotNode.CreateChild().CreateChild();
        var plane = baseNode.CreateComponent<StaticModel>();
        plane.Model = CoreAssets.Models.Sphere;

        var cameraNode = _scene.CreateChild();
        _camera = cameraNode.CreateComponent<Camera>();
        cameraNode.Position = new Vector3(10, 15, 10) / 1.75f;
        cameraNode.Rotation = new Quaternion(-0.121f, 0.878f, -0.305f, -0.35f);

        Node lightNode = cameraNode.CreateChild();
        var light = lightNode.CreateComponent<Light>();
        light.LightType = LightType.Point;
        light.Range = 100;
        light.Brightness = 1.3f;

        int size = 3;
        baseNode.Scale = new Vector3(size * 1.5f, 1, size * 1.5f);

        var imageStream = await new HttpClient().GetStreamAsync("some 512 * 512 jpg image");
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageStream.CopyTo(ms);

        var image = new Image();
        var isLoaded = image.Load(new MemoryBuffer(ms));
        if (!isLoaded)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        var texture = new Texture2D();
        //var isTextureLoaded = texture.Load(new MemoryBuffer(ms.ToArray()));
        var isTextureLoaded = texture.SetData(image);
        if (!isTextureLoaded)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        var material = new Material();
        material.SetTexture(TextureUnit.Diffuse, texture);
        material.SetTechnique(0, CoreAssets.Techniques.Diff, 0, 0);
        plane.SetMaterial(material);

        try
        {
            await _plotNode.RunActionsAsync(new EaseBackOut(new RotateBy(2f, 0, 360, 0)));
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Create a material from a 2D Texture, you can use Material.FromImage .

Refer following documentation for more detail.

```
model.SetMaterial(Material.FromImage("earth.jpg"));
```

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Urho.Material/
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Urho.Material.FromImage/p/System.String/

```
private async void CreateScene()
{


   _scene = new Scene();
   _octree = _scene.CreateComponent<Octree>();

   _plotNode = _scene.CreateChild();
   var baseNode = _plotNode.CreateChild().CreateChild();


   var plane = _plotNode.CreateComponent<StaticModel>();
   plane.Model = CoreAssets.Models.Sphere;
   plane.SetMaterial(Material.FromImage("earth.jpg"));

   var cameraNode = _scene.CreateChild();
   _camera = cameraNode.CreateComponent<Camera>();
   cameraNode.Position = new Vector3(10, 15, 10) / 1.75f;

   cameraNode.Rotation = new Quaternion(-0.121f, 0.878f, -0.305f, -0.35f);

   Node lightNode = cameraNode.CreateChild();
   var light = lightNode.CreateComponent<Light>();
   light.LightType = LightType.Point;
   light.Range = 100;
   light.Brightness = 1.3f;

   int size = 3;
   baseNode.Scale = new Vector3(size * 1.5f, 1, size * 1.5f);

   Renderer.SetViewport(0, new Viewport(_scene, _camera, null));

   try
   {
       await _plotNode.RunActionsAsync(new EaseBackOut(new RotateBy(2f, 0, 360, 0)));
   }
   catch (OperationCanceledException) { }

}
```